# Push Notification not working in iPhone 3GS. It works on latest IOS devices like iPhone 4,4s,5

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, notifications, push-notification

I have checked Push Notification in iPhone 4,4s,5 with IOS version 5.1 to 7.0 and it works perfectly. Later on, i check in iPhone 3GS device with IOS version 6.1.2 and facing the weird exception as i won't able to get any notification in iPhone 3GS device.

I have rechecked certificates, pem file but not getting any notification. This delegate method is also called and i received device token in iPhone 3GS device.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
```

But, while sending any notification to the concerned iPhone 3GS device via PHP script i won't get any response. My assumption is that Apple might be not sending push notification to their older devices.

I have undergone this tutorial keenly but all in vain for iPhone 3GS device.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Kindly give me your valuable feedback if any to rectify this issues.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with aps certificates (at least with one of them) if notifications are received on other devices. Note that **development** device token is different from ad-hoc or **production** (release) device token. When you are testing from xcode you get development token and you have to use development certificate and sandbox server connection to deliver notification. When testing with ad-hoc or other release-build you have to use production token, production certificate & production server connection. Also make sure to check device settings (notifications).

Comment: @rokjarc: I am sure you found the reason. If you'd post an answer, I'll up vote it.

Comment: @rokjarc: Thanks for the support. I know the device token is application specific and it would be changed from application to application. Device token is also different in development and distribution profile. I have generated different certificates for distribution and do the required testing but not getting any notification in the iPhone 3GS device. I am getting notification in other devices from the same profile. I have also checked the device setting and it is OK in the Settings->Notification Center.

Comment: Actually Apples's server uses SSL data (certificate info) to distinguish between applications. Production APNS token (for example) can actually be the same for one device for all applications (not 100% sure about that). If this 3GS device is a phone you use for development try removing all provisioning profiles from it, delete your app and reinstall. Then test again.

Comment: @vikingosegundo: i hope i did but OP's problem seems to persist

Comment: @Sandy: it is the OS Apple is concerned about, not the _age_ of a certain device. This really doesn't sound like the root of your problem. I tested an ancient iPod running 6.1 and works flawlessly.

Comment: on your 3GS.. you receive others push notifications? It is jailbroken?

Comment: @rokjarc: I have also checked in iPod with os version 6.1.2 and got the push notification. But, in case of iPhone 3GS i am getting only device token. Php script successfully works on the apple devices  like iPhone 4,4s,5 and iPod with the os version greater than 6.0 and got the desire notification but in iPhone 3gs while processing the same script getting successful message but no any notification.
 :(

Comment: @TonyMkeny: Yes, i am getting other push notification of Facebook and other apps which i downloaded from the app store. but in my own application i am not getting any notification.

Answer (score 2):

Since you receive notifications on other devices then it is nothing wrong with your .PEM certificates or communication with Apples's APS server.

Things you should be aware of when debugging this situation are:

- device APNS token for development mode and production mode are different
- device APNS tokens can be the same across the applications (at least for the same publisher). Apple's server uses SSL data (certificate used to initiate the connection) to distinguish between the applications - not the token data
- AdHoc mode (installed with iPhone Configuration Utility, TestFlight...) is same as production mode
- a no brainer: when sending to app in development mode a development certificate should with sandbox server connection (and development APNS token of course)
- on development devices sometimes *bad things do happen*. Delete profiles, delete application, restart device and try again. Don't forget to check and recheck Notification Center settings. Yo might need to change a setting and then change back to get the desired effect.
- sometimes problem is misdiagnosed as "certain device" does not get notifications when actually certain type of notification doesn't get trough. Or one uses different messages to test delivery on different devices and it is actually the message that is the culprit. For example unescaped ČŠŽ...

Comment: I am appreciating your efforts and thanks for your timing. 
I have researched all the things which you mentioned. I checked Notification Centre in 3GS device and it is fine. I am working in the Production profile and getting the Device token that means delegate method is working in 3GS device.

Comment: I have some assumptions which i listed below.
1. Apple might be not sending push notification to their older devices.
2. The Php script which i am calling is having some problem with their older devices.
3. I have done something wrong while creating SSl certificate(PEM file). This certificate can work on iPhone device > 4.0 and could have some problem in iPhone 3GS device.

Comment: Actually i'm still thinking about your question but no a-ha moment yet... your 3 assumptions don't seem probable. Could it be the problem with token handling? Maybe the app-code or php code messes-up the token for this device?

Comment: Because SSL defines the app that will be triggered and token defines the device. Just a hunch: can you use iCloud with this device (are proper credentials entered)?